# Revert changes from git using VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, git

noob question from someone who just started using VSCode and SFDX for Salesforce development.

When you make changes to a project, git tracks those changes, this is nothing new. But when you want to revert changes, vscode removes those changes locally but the changes remain inside the org. How do I click the revert button on vscode and delete the files locally as well as inside the org?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what files you're talking about, what org you're working against, and how much the org matches your source (if it's not a scratch org).

If you're utilizing [scratch orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_push_md_to_scratch_org.htm),  you can use `sfdx force:source:push` to sync those changes to the scratch org. If you feel it's gotten messy - you can also discard it and spin up a new one with your local as the truth.

If you're working on a non-scratch org, there's some considerations.

- Is the metadata in the org the same as source or are multiple people working out of it?
- Is it old or will it continue to be used?
- Do you know what files were removed (assuming you already used git to revert the changes)
- Is it a lot of things to delete?

If it's a couple classes or things that delete easily

- In VS Code, you can right click on a file a select `SFDX: Delete this from Project and Org`.
- Use the CLI and specify the file: `sfdx force:source:delete -u orgAlias -p force-app/main/default/class/MyClassToDelete.cls`.

Otherwise, if it's a bunch of files with dependencies, it might make sense to build a [destructiveChanges.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm) and utilize `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d /pathToDestructivePackage`. Make sure that a package.xml that contains no compnents to deploy is in that path along with your destructiveChanges.xml that does specify the files to delete.

The **good news** is that what I described for scratch orgs above is in beta with [Summer '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sandboxes_source_tracking.htm) for developer and developer pro sandboxes. Soon you may be able to do the same as I described above with Scratch orgs.